# systemd: how to print a service's default configuration?

Tags: systemd, configuration

I take a simple example: `systemd-timesyncd.service`
This service is responsible to keep time accurate (like the regular NTP server, but it only act as a lightweight client, and synchronize to only one server at a time).

The default configuration file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` is empty so the compile-time parameters are used.

If I download the source code, I can see what are the default parameters.
If I get my specific distribution (Debian) patches I can see the custom default parameters (if any).

For example the NTP servers used by default are `time{1,2,3,4}.google.com`
And Debian replace them by `{0,1,2,3}.debian.pool.ntp.org` at compile-time.

I can see which server is currently used: `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service`
This allow to have an idea about the default configuration. But this is far incomplete, even if it is probably often easy to guess the remaining servers.

Question: is there a standard way to display the default parameters for a systemd service?

Comment: What about `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd.service`? Are you sure compile-time parameters are being used, and there are no options being set from other directories that `systemd` uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: is there a standard way to display the default parameters for a systemd service?

There is no standard way to display the default parameters for a systemd service.

Many services expose some parameters on the bus.

For example:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties GetAll "s" ""
```

shows properties of the manager itself.

Output contains [`RuntimeWatchdogSec`, `ShutdownWatchdogSec`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#RuntimeWatchdogSec=)(as `RuntimeWatchdogUSec` and `ShutdownWatchdogUSec`), [`LogLevel`, `DefaultStandardOutput`, `DefaultStandardError`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#LogLevel=) etc.

> I take a simple example: systemd-timesyncd.service

See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1589

Comment: "call" available since [`v218`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/781fa93815fafd02b5287ef5).  [`systemctl show`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#show%20PATTERN...%7CJOB...) shows properties of the manager itself too.

Comment: you can use `dbus-send`: `dbus-send --print-reply --system --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll string:''`:)